# Discord bot not loading

Tags: discord.js

My discord bot works properly but today something sus is happening. when i run the bot the thing is just loading and it just says

[The terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKLAQ.png)

It doesnt run the bot. Its supposed to log "Beta Pog" but its not has this happened to you?

I am using a event handler and its a simple console.log()

but its not working, I tried to restart it but it still doesnt work.

Code for the ready event

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    execute(bot) {
        console.log(`Beta Pog`)
        bot.user.setActivity('with beta testing')
    },
};
```

Comment: Is this module added to the command handler?

Comment: Its a event handler and it has some other events and theres also a message event which has a command handler

Comment: So you said it used to work properly, that means the handler is attached fine. Could you try regenerating your bot token and try logging in with the new one

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with the token it was working yesterday and i got no dm from discord safety

Answer (score 0):

I would steer clear of command handlers until you have a solid knowledge of javascript and discord.js in general.

We cannot debug your problem because we do not have the bot command handler code.

Here is how you would do this, using 1 index.js file and simply log "beta pog"

```js
// require packages
const Discord = require("discord.js");
// initialise the bot
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Beta Pog`);
  bot.user.setActivity('with beta testing');
});
```

I would recommend using `;` semi colons, it saves debugging nasty errors later

Also, I am unfamiliar with `node .`, try the long version `node index.js` etc. If the issue persists, try deleting the node modules folder, and doing `npm install` to recreate the packages in case it is caused by a corrupt package.

[Here](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files) is a simple command handler, with a guide to follow

Comment: `node .` makes it so that it goes to the default main code as labeled in the `package.json` file.